# How to calculate the wave front set for the characteristic function of a 2-dimensional ball?

Tags: characteristic-functions, fourier-transform, singularity, microlocal-analysis

I've been trying to show that the wave front set for the characteristic function of the open ball, $B(0,1)$, is given by the boundary normal vectors $\{(x,\xi) \in S^1 \times \mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}$: $x \|\xi\}$ (i.e. $t\xi = x\in S^1$, $t\in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$). I'd be very happy if someone showed me how to prove the statement.

Definition of the wave front set:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_front_set

Comment: I would like to see an explicit proof/calculation of something like this as well. Just to clarify, though: by "wave front set for the characteristic function" you're really saying the wave front set of the distribution that is integration against the characteristic function, correct?

Answer (score 2):

This is shown in detail in Section 4 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.1778.pdf).  The idea is to transform to coordinates in terms of which the characteristic function of the ball is a tensor product between a smooth function and a one-dimensional Heaviside distribution.  Of course, in this case polar coordinates do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

you'll find all the necessary informations related to these kinds of characteristic functions and some general technics to calculate wave front set in

https://www.icts.res.in/sites/default/files/Jan_Boman_Lecture_Notes_0.pdf

Besides, this article is very easy to read. The second part of the document is related to the interplay between Radon transform and wave front set, but though it is worth reading, it is far form your subject